# ASP.NET Dynamic Data GridView Control Replacement / Substitution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, asp.net-dynamic-data

Is there an easy way to replace / substitute the standard Microsoft ASP.NET GridView control in a Dynamic Data EF project? I know there are plenty of component vendors that ship GridView control with out of the box functions that go way beyond what the default ASP.NET GridView provide.

Considering this project is using the following: Standard ASP.NET C# 4.0 Dynamic-Data EF website project (VS 2010).

Specifically, here would be my requirements:

1. The main purpose is to swap the current ASP.NET GridView control
   with a more powerful one (see specific requirements for the GridView
   below).
2. Easy migration of the project (not too much code to re-write
   to substitute the grid).

Gridview specific features:

1. Support for freezing header-rows and ability to pin specific columns.
2. Inline editing (granted, the standard GridView control supports it already).
3. Excel like column filtering (i.e. multiple choices based on column values).
4. Column re-ordering.
5. Out of the box group-by capabilities.

Have you ever been through such a substitution exercise?
If you have I would appreciate your feedback!

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are a few who support Dynamic Data like Wijmo grid and Telerik grids but I've not tried the most recent version for compatibility. Telerik may be you best bet I would ask on their forums.

Comment: Thanks, will check the Telerik control then.